# Problema al crear un registro de usuarios en PHP / mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando crear un registro de usuarios que funcione desde mi pagina `index.php` donde esta el **login** para ingresar sin embargo por mas que corrijo el código me indica que el usuario no lo reconoce.

¿Me pueden decir en que estoy fallando por favor?

La base de datos creada `parcial` tiene una **tabla** a nombre de `usuarios`, la columna de `usuarios` se llama `NomUsuario` y contraseña `PassUsuario`.

El archivo conexion ya me enlaza la base de datos como tal, pero **no me reconoce ningun usuario  y me dice el error**:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\parcial\registro.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Password in C:\xampp\htdocs\parcial\registro.php on line 5
> ```

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE NomUsuario = '$_POST[username]' and PassUsuario= '$_POST[Password]";


$result = $conexion->query($buscarUsuario);



$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {

    echo "<br/>". "El Nombre de Usuario ya a sido tomado." . "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='registro.php'>Por favor escoga otro Nombre</a>";

}

 else{

     $form_pass = $_POST['password'];

$hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

     $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (NomUsuario, PassUsuario)
     VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$hash')";

if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {


    echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";
        echo "<h4>" . "Bienvenido: " . $_POST['username'] . "</h4>" . "\n\n";
echo "<h5>" . "Hacer Login: " . "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>" . "</h5>";
}

     else {
echo "Error al crear el usuario." . $query . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
}
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion);

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Registro</h2>

        <form role="form" name="registro" action="php/index.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
          </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirmar Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirmar Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>

            <script>alert(\"Registro exitoso. Proceda a logearse\");window.location='../index.php';</script>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

---

Fíjate que me dieron ahora estos errores al hacer las correcciones x.x:

Warning: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 5

Warning: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 23

Warning: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parcial\registro.php on line 28

Answer (score 1):

Encontre estos errores en tu codigo, corrigelo y me dices si se fue el error
**Esta parte:**

```
$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE NomUsuario = '$_POST[username]' and PassUsuario= '$_POST[Password]";
```

**A:**

```
$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE NomUsuario = '".$_POST['username']."' and PassUsuario= '".$_POST['Password']."'";
```

**Esta parte:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (NomUsuario, PassUsuario)
     VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$hash')";
```

**A:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (NomUsuario, PassUsuario)
     VALUES ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$hash."')";
```

Espero se corrija tu error. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

hola debes recordar que la variable de php `$_POST` llega como un arreglo y tanto `username` como `Password` son campos de este arreglo y deben estar encerrado por comillas osea debe quedar algo asi... `$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios
WHERE NomUsuario = '".$_POST['username']."' and PassUsuario= '".$_POST['Password']."' ";`

Answer (score 1):

Los problemas en tu código son los siguientes:

1. Las advertencias las obtienes porque nunca estás validando si ya se enviaron los datos por `$_POST`, es decir, apenas ingresas la página intentas "logear" sin que los datos todavía hayan sido completados.
2. En la línea 5 estas usando `$_POST[Password]`, pero debería ser `$_POST[password]`. Aún que viendo las líneas debajo, no deberías chequear el `password` sino solo el `username`.
3. "*Por suerte*" tenes un error de sintaxis en tu `Javascript` lo cual evita que seas redireccionado a otro archivo, puntualmente me refiero a esta línea:

   ```
    <script>alert(\"Registro exitoso. Proceda a logearse\");window.location='../index.php';</script>
   ```

   Esto deberías eliminarlo (?)
4. Tu código [es vulnerable a inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597)

#### Solución:

Te dejo una posible solución a los primeros 3 problemas, el 4to lo dejo para que lo investigues.

```
<?php

// ACA Controlamos si se enviaron los datos del formulario por POST
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

  include("conexion.php");

  // ACA saque "AND PassUsuario = ..." porque solo necesitas validar 
  // si el nombre de usuario existe
  $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * 
    FROM usuarios
    WHERE NomUsuario = '$_POST[username]'";

  $result = $conexion->query($buscarUsuario);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count == 1) {

    echo "<br/>" . "El Nombre de Usuario ya a sido tomado." . "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='registro.php'>Por favor escoga otro Nombre</a>";
  } else {

    $form_pass = $_POST['password'];
    $hash = password_hash($form_pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (NomUsuario, PassUsuario)
      VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$hash')";

    if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {

      echo "<br />" . "<h2>" . "Usuario Creado Exitosamente!" . "</h2>";
      echo "<h4>" . "Bienvenido: " . $_POST['username'] . "</h4>" . "\n\n";
      echo "<h5>" . "Hacer Login: " . "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>" . "</h5>";
    } else {
      echo "Error al crear el usuario." . $query . "<br>" . $conexion->error;
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($conexion);
}

?>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Registro</h2>

        <form role="form" name="registro" action="php/index.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario">Nombre de usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirmar Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirmar Contrase&ntilde;a" required>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Registrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**PD:** En `PHP`, no estas haciendo nada con el confirmar contraseña.
**PD2:** Diría que el `action` del `form` esta mal, que debería ser `action="registro.php"`